# Regex Component SSIS Package

Tags: c#, regex, ssis

I have a little strange requirement my table has values with various special characters and I need to edit them to suite client requirement.

My table is as below

```
 **Name**
.xy z., Jr
Jr, .xy z., Jr
Jr. xy z., Sr
,Jr xy, z, Jr
.Jr .xy, z., Jr
Sr\ .xy z., Jr
Ser, xy , z., Jr
./Sr xy,/ z., Jr
<<sr, xy z, Jr
SR, .xy z., Jr
[]sa, .xy z., Jr
ps xy z., Jr
asa xy z., Jr
asad .xy z., Jr
bs/ .xy z., Jr
p[], .xy z., Jr
lold.,.xy z., Jr
scs., .xy z., Jr
losdj .xy z., Jr
.xy z., Jr
.xy./z., Jr
sa .xy z., Jr
```

My end column should be as

```
Jr,xy,z,Jr.
```

or any of this form just that special characters should be removed.

I thought of splitting the columns and then removing the special characters
but the problem is when I have 2 continuous special characters at once then I would have a column with just special character in it I wanted to know If there is a way to solve it.

Comment: How do you get `,` in between `xy` and `z`

Comment: later adding the , in SSIS package

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to convert all values to a predetermined format? Are `xy` and `z` names? Are they always the same? What are `asa` and `asad` etc?

Comment: all values to predefined format xy and z are first name and last name just for notation i changed it as such asa and asad might be the prefix so asa,xy,z,jr should be my format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try a replace with this regex?

```
^(?=.*?(\w+)\W*(\w+)\W+([JS]r)$).*
```

And replace with:

```
$3,$1,$2,$3.
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/aD2zU5).

If the `Sr` in your strings was a typo, then you can do:

```
^(?=.*?(\w+)\W*(\w+)\W+Jr$).*
```

And replace with:

```
Jr,$1,$2,Jr.
```

---

EDIT: Okay, since there might be missing parts, try:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"^\W*(\w*?)\W*(\b\w+\b)\W*(\b\w+\b)\W*(\w*)$", @"$1,$2,$3,$4.").Trim(new Char[] {','});
```

Comment: Awesome thank you :) just a doubt i need asa,xy,z,jr as well any thing in front should just come in

Comment: @user2588812 Huh, so you need to get the letters at the beginning? What should `.xy z., Jr` become? If it can become `,xy,z,jr`, then maybe [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/aH7yS6)?

Comment: but cant i just make it xy,z,jr if i dont have any first name?

Comment: @user2588812 Okay, I'll add something for that and edit my answer in a few minutes

Comment: I have a doubt if i have a requirement like Jr or Sr or II or III come in middle then they need to be at the end how should we do

Comment: This is my actual data **Name**
.xy z., Jr
Jr, .xy z., Jr
Jr. xy z., Sr
,Jr xy, z, Jr
.Jr .xy, z., Jr
Sr\ .xy z., Jr
Ser, xy , z., Jr
./Sr xy,/ z., Jr
<<sr, xy z, Jr

Comment: my out put should be like in the format of xy,z,Jr. or xy,z,Sr.

Comment: @Zack Could you put that on pastebin or somewhere where it's easier to read than in a comment, then give me the link to it? Also, it would be nice if you put what it should become as well there.

Comment: @Zack Yours is quite different from the original question. All the same, try [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/kN4yU8).

Comment: Thank you soo much :) it works perfectly great :). But one small doubt if I Have 4 Then how should that be. for example http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=NdV8rgHQ  first two cases Please check and help

Comment: @Zack You might want to use the help of a few loops to do something like that, because if you try regex with 3 names and a title, you will get an empty element in the resulting string if there are only 2 names. Here's an example with loops: [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/fqbIpS)

Comment: how to add . at the end of every line

Comment: @Zack Oops, I forgot the dot. You simply add `+ "."` to the string. I also edited the code in the link above.

Comment: thats great how do I implement this code in SSIS script component do you have any idea about it? Thank you for the Help I hope I am not getting on to your nerve :)

Comment: @Zack Sorry, I don't know how to do that... I happen to only know about Regex and C#. I wouldn't hesitate to help you if I knew SSIS :(

Comment: can you please check for GRIIFIN CURLISE B and DOMINQUE ALBERT III it is giving wierd results

Comment: @Zack Oh, I should have known that ^^; I ignored cases where the `I` could be in a name. [Try this fix](http://ideone.com/CdPWGB).

Comment: sorry to disturb you again but the solution is not working fine with couple of combinations and your help would be greatly appreciated.Examples are  LALANI SONALI
DOAN, TRINH MAI THI
KLEINPETER HEIDI I
BUI TUOI T                 
CHAVEZ III RUBEN I         
MAFFEI   III EMILE         
MROCZKOWSKI JOHN R III

Comment: @Zack A pastebin would be nice :)

Comment: hhttp://ideone.com/CdPWGB sorry for the above comment :) Please find the ideone link for example

Comment: @Zack Is anything wrong with it? I just see you forgot to add the dot at the end, but is that it? maybe you could come to [this chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46067/tcl)? (it's just a chatroom I made and using for various things)